# I have DLC and want 2 PSN accounts

Tags: psn

So I have an online PSN account with DLC and I want to make a second online PSN account and I want to keep the DLC. Would the DLC be on both online PSN accounts?

Comment: I'm going to guess no.  DLC is locked to your specific PSN account, and will use that authentication whenever you go online.

Comment: It's unclear whether you are asking about the ownership of the DLC or the use of the DLC. Are you asking about whether the DLC is owned by both PSN IDs or whether the DLC can be used online by both PSN IDs on the same console (as in an online pass or multiplayer maps or something)? Perhaps citing the specific DLC could illuminate what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Content downloaded onto an activated console [is accessible to all users on the same console](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/LittleBigPlanet-Pod/How-do-I-share-DLC-across-each-User-on-the-same-PS3/td-p/29656648)** as long as the console is activated with the owner of the content's PSN ID. [Some content specifically prohibits this](http://www.gtplanet.net/beware-gran-turismo-5s-dlc-locked-to-single-psn-account/).

**Content is not shared in the store across PSN IDs** and only the account that purchased the content will have the ability to install the content. To share content across accounts, simply have the owner of the content activate the console on their account and install the content on the same console.

[For content purchased prior to November 18, 2011, you were allowed to have that content on up to 5 PS3s, and **content purchased after November 18, 2011 is only allowed to be installed and activated on up to 2 PS3s**](http://www.1up.com/news/psn-purchases-only-used-two-systems).

[**Sharing across multiple PSN IDs violates the TOS** and some users have been banned for it](http://www.strategyinformer.com/news/9908/updated-terms-of-service-agreement-ends-psn-game-sharing).

Answer (score 1):

If you bought the DLC on your ps3 on one account you can make a new one and go to the playstation store. When you are there you can goto system downloads and once there click the little blue arrow and it will download the DLC/camo/game. Then you will be able to have it on both accounts.