# DLC and multiple profiles on one PS3

Tags: ps3

I don't play ps3 often, so I have a profile to separate my saves from my husband's but no PSN account. However, I'm quite enamored with Bioshock Infinite and I'm excited for the upcoming DLC "Burial at Sea". If my husband purchases the DLC, will I be able to play it in my profile? Or will we need to purchase two copies? Will this change if I sign up for PSN?

(Inspired by [I have DLC and want 2 PSN accounts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127438/i-have-dlc-and-want-2-psn-accounts), but I didn't see any question covering this particular use case on the site already.)

Comment: Actually, it's the same question and use case. User has DLC and wants to use it on 2 PSN accounts. You may specifically say, "on one PS3," whereas the other question does not, but the question is still, "Can I share DLC across PSN accounts?"

Comment: @skovacs1 I don't have a PSN account. I just have a profile.

Comment: It's just one PS3, right? I think all users, with or without PSN accounts, can play content (games or dlc) as long as an active PSN account on the system has access to it. Can't test right now though, so comment instead of an answer

Comment: Gotcha. I missed that fine line. I'm writing an answer for the other, but it's identical to what my answer to this question is so I may have gotten ahead of myself.

Comment: If the answer is exactly the same, regardless of profile or PSN ID, then I'm inclined to think they're dupes.

Comment: @fbueckert It looks like the answer to the linked question is a subset of the answer to mine. I guess they should probably be merged?

Comment: @fbueckert That's where I was going, but just because the answer to one encompasses the answer to the other does not make the question the same. Sharing from one PSN ID to users on the same console is cool, but sharing across PSN IDs violates TOS so asking about each specifically, while depending on the same information is not the exact same question. There's a meta on this. I'll dig it up, but I'm fine with whatever is decided.

Comment: @skovacs1 We're hashing it out in chat right now.  I feel a minor change in the question doesn't warrant a completely new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you never create a PSN ID for your other profile, there should be no problems and you will not have to purchase multiple copies. If you sign up for a PSN ID for that user, then you could still play with that DLC, but at the risk of violating the Terms of Service and possibly getting accounts banned.

**Content downloaded onto an activated console [is accessible to all users on the same console](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/LittleBigPlanet-Pod/How-do-I-share-DLC-across-each-User-on-the-same-PS3/td-p/29656648)** as long as the console is activated with the owner of the content's PSN ID. [Some content specifically prohibits this](http://www.gtplanet.net/beware-gran-turismo-5s-dlc-locked-to-single-psn-account/).

**Content is not shared in the store across PSN IDs** and only the account that purchased the content will have the ability to install the content. To share content across accounts, simply have the owner of the content activate the console on their account and install the content on the same console.

[For content purchased prior to November 18, 2011, you were allowed to have that content on up to 5 PS3s, and **content purchased after November 18, 2011 is only allowed to be installed and activated on up to 2 PS3s**](http://www.1up.com/news/psn-purchases-only-used-two-systems).

[**Sharing across multiple PSN IDs violates the TOS** and some users have been banned for it](http://www.strategyinformer.com/news/9908/updated-terms-of-service-agreement-ends-psn-game-sharing).